# ControlValueAccessor not working when component inserted dynamically

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

InputFieldComponent component developed using `implements ControlValueAccessor`

```js
constructor(public cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {

}

onTouchedCallback = () => { };
onChangeCallback: any = () => { };

// register a handler that should be fired when something in the view has changed
registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
  this.onChangeCallback = fn;
}

// registers a handler specifically for when a control receives a touch event.
registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
  this.onTouchedCallback = fn;
}

// writes new values from the form model into the view or any DOM property
writeValue(value: string): void {
  if (value !== this.innerValue) {
    this.innerValue = value;
  }
}

// textbox input change
onChange(event: any): void {
  this.onChangeCallback(event.target.value);
}
```

added dynamically like this.

```js
const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(InputFieldComponent);
const newComponent = container.createComponent(componentFactory);
```

Set up

```js
form.addControl("firstname",
                new FormControl("Some TEXT ", Validators.required));

newComponent.instance.formControlName = "firstname"
```

trying to fire `writeValue` by writing below line :

```js
newComponent.instance.cd.detectChanges();
```

but no luck, how do to solve this problem?  i want to see "Some TEXT" in textbox value.

normally if i used this component html, it is working expected.

here stackblitz link for what i tried : -

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-input-init-value-d34jls

Comment: can you create stackblitz

Comment: yeah, i am in progress to creating stackblitz

Comment: @Chellappan - i have updated stackblitz, thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you doing this way?

Comment: because we have lots of components and do not want to use ngswitch in html, what's your recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing Template Driven Forms (Using `ngModel`) and Reactive Forms, which [is deprecated](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel-is-deprecated) in your Angular version and will be removed in a future version of Angular.

What I would suggest, although it feels hacky, is to input the `FormControl` to the dynamic `ControlValueAccessor` component you just created: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-input-init-value-fuxwks

I highly suggest you re-think of a design for whatever you're trying to achieve.

P.S. use `<ng-template></ng-template>` instead of `<template></template>`. This is encouraged since Angular 4.

Comment: your answer solve the problem, but i would not like to put formcontrol to ControlValueAccessor component, it is hacky as you suggest :)

Comment: @Var I agree, that's why I would suggest re-thinking the entire design.